# Meaning of "rock" in "rock your meeting."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a passage from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> He checked his watch. "We'll be fine--don't worry about us. Just do what you have to do. Rock your meeting."

Neal said the above. He is Georgie's husband. The setting is outside their home. Neal is about to leave with the kids to vacation, but Georgie can't come because something came up at work. Their about to leave and Neal said to Georgie to "rock your meeting". What does that mean?

Comment: Same as "rock your world" or "We will, we will rock you!".

Comment: Yes, **rock** here is a verb in the imperative mood. "Make your meeting proceed in a really cool way", "do your best at the meeting", "impress other participants during your meeting", something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Definition 3 for Rock (Transitive Verb) at merriam-webster fits here:

> to rouse to excitement (as by performing rock music)

Neal may be trying to boost Georgie's confidence and ego for a meeting at Georgie's work.